# How to remote debug CasperJS with Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, phantomjs, remote-debugging, casperjs

What are the steps to debug CasperJS scripts in Chrome? I'm trying to debug on my windows 8.1.

1) my test c:\temp\googletestin.js have:

```
debugger;

casper.test.begin('Google search retrieves 10 or more results',3, function suite(test) {

    casper.start("http://www.google.com.br/", function() {
        this.echo(">>Number 1");
        test.assertTitle("Google", "Title home page google");

        casper.echo(">>Number 2");
        test.assertExists('form[action="/search"]', "find form search");

        casper.echo(">>Number 3");
        this.fill('form[action="/search"]', {
            q: "casperjs"
        }, true);

        this.echo(">>Number 4");
        casper.capture('test.png', undefined, {
        format: 'png',
        quality: 75
        });

    })

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

2) open cmd.exe

3) do the command line

```
>casperjs test c:\temp\googletesting.js --remote-debugger-port=9222 --remote-debugger-autorun=yes
```

ps: the test running until the end normally

4) open chrome and field that url: `http:localhost:9222`

5) page is blank

6) open console (f12) and do: `__run();` but nothing is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In step 3 you need to pass the debugger options into CasperJS and not the script where it would be accessible through `casper.cli`. You also should not let the script autostart (`--remote-debugger-autorun=yes`) otherwise it will run before you can debug it. As you correctly stated, you can then open Chrome/Safari and call `__run()` to trigger the script execution.

```
casperjs --remote-debugger-port=9222 test yourScript.js
```

Comment: doesn't work. page message "this page is not accessible" and I do the step 6 show on console: __run is not defined

Comment: Ok, it didn't for me when I used autostart, but it does work when used without. Please check by answer again.

Comment: do you start chrome.exe on remote way before run the command line "casperjs --remote..."?. Like this:

c:\program files\google\chrome\chrome.exe --remote-debugger-port-9222

or do the steps that i mentioned?

tks for you attention.

Comment: No, I start chrome as usual without a specific commandline argument and then navigate to http://localhost:9222, then click on the about:blank link, navigate to the console tab and enter `__run()`. I guess I can try it out with a specific commandline argument.

Comment: when i do the test with a phantomjs works!.
phantomjs --remote-debugger-port=9000 "c:\temp\phantom.js